# Working PHP 5.2 code yields very frustrating PHP 5.3 parse errors that I cannot explain, help needed

Tags: php, parse-error

The following code

```
<?php
try
{
    $var=0;
}
    catch(Exception $e)
{
    $var=1;
}
?>
```

in index.php yields

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/site/public_html/index.php on line 3

The code is working on PHP 5.2.8, Zend Engine 2.2.0, Apache 2.2.21 (test server), but throws the parse error on PHP 5.3.3, Apache  1.3.42 (production machine!). Of course the actual code is more complex, but I reduced it to a bare minimum as above, which throws the parse error, too.

As you can imagine this is extremely frustrating, it should be such a straight forward thing.

I tried looking for hidden special chars in the source, there are none. There are other odd parse errors across the code, which I can see if I comment out the above. It really is weird.

Please suggest something, I'm at my wit's end, I don't know what to to with this. Let me know what other information you need.

Many thanks!

Comment: this is perfectly valid code in PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3, I could verify it on my machine. Is there something before the opening <?php tag in your file ?

Comment: It also works perfectly on 5.4.

Comment: that code is valid. the problem must be somewhere else

Comment: @Vlad: the code on line 3 is simply {

Comment: then post the first lines of code from the file. we can't help you otherwise

Comment: That's EXACTLY it, but the parse error is before that.

Comment: do you really have in that try catch $var = something?

Comment: The parse error may be due to a file upstream - check which files and code are invoked prior to this one.

Comment: @Vlad: the EXACT code shown yields the EXACT error shown.

Comment: @Ansari: that is very interesting, I'll have a look, can you elaborate?

Comment: Well I was thinking this file might be included by another file or something like that, but on reading your other responses it sounds like this is standalone and this file is the point of entry for the request. Is that the case?

Comment: I have deleted index.php on the server, re-created it there via cpanel, edited it with the code above, still the same error! I did this just to exclude file encoding problems. Still parse error on a perfectly valid piece of code! This is one of those hair-pulling things. Aaargh!

Comment: You mentioned some other parse errors - perhaps they could lend a clue as to what's going on? The root of this error probably lies outside this code snippet and somewhere in your environment.

Comment: Why would you mix up such 2 different versions, you see where this leads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you forgot to append a semi colon before the opening curly braces.
Or you are running a php version < 5.0

Comment: Where, surely not after the "try"?

Comment: of course not. just before that you must have a syntax error. don't know without much code. pot the whole script or something. because that piece of code is valid and doesn't help

Comment: Dear Vlad, the EXACT code above, placed EXACTLY like you see it in an index.php file and executed on the production machine yields the EXACT error you see above. There is no more/other code in the test I'm subjecting to your opinion. That's it. I know the code is valid, hence my immense frustration with this.

Comment: do you use the auto_prepend_file directive?

Comment: also can you give me the url to your production machine

Comment: it maybe far fetched but try something else: access your production url and append ?-s. do you by any chance see the source code?

Comment: The source code is the one above. You can see it here: spinstudio.ro. Yes, it's weird and frustrating.

Comment: @webmaster nevermind my previous comments. i'm sure some piece of code is included somehow in your index.php my best guess is that you have auto_prepend_file activated and puls some code from a remote source. delete all the code and do a simple echo 'worl'; see what happens

Comment: I'm sorry I can't make you understand this better. The index.php file you see in action right now contains ONLY the code above, EXACTLY (!!) as it is. There is no includes, requires, or any other code in that file. The contents of the file are EXACTLY what you see in my original post. I hope this makes it clear. You can see the result (the parse error) for yourself. However, this gives me an idea, I'll check the .htaccess, make sure there aren't some redirects affecting this.

Comment: As you can see now, it says "world", it works, but that's NOT the point! Why does it yield a parse error on a perfectly good piece of code?!

Comment: i do understand that. thats why i said to delete the code and put a simple echo to see if it works. also, there can be a case of exploit in which an attacker can trigger auto_prepend_file whithout you knowing it, which makes your script to load some code before the one you have listed. i've seen this happen

Comment: are you sure it's php 5.3? do a php info. exceptions are not supported until php 5.0.x

Comment: Hm, interesting! How do I check that (the attack, I mean)?

Comment: since the simple echo worked it's safe to say that an explot isn't the case. the only thing i can think of is that the production is running and older php version that doesnt support exception. i'm out of ideeas :)

Comment: :)). it's php4. that's why it doesn't work

Comment: why would you thing you have PHP 5.3 on the production server?

Comment: Damn, you're right. It's 4.4.9 according to phpinfo()! It says 5.3.3 in CPanel, though! What the hell is this?! This really is idiotic ... Including of myself.

Comment: you may have mixed php installation and the apache is configured to serve files with php4 instead of php5. switch to apache2

Comment: Currently trying to setup the server for Apache 2.x, PHP 5.3, and I'll get back. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Solved. Misleading PHP version info in CPanel (why does that appear like so?! It's really stupid -- just show the version the server is currently running, for God's sake!), server actually set up to run older version. It doesn't work at all now, but that's another issue. The current issue was solved by configuring the server to run PHP 5. Thanks, Vlad.